# russian characters not accepted in php / phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, text, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a website in 3 languages: english, dutch and russian.

There's a little CMS where the user can update the text on the website.

everything works good, except for the russian text.. If I enter any russian text in the form in the CMS, I get "????" in the phpmyadmin database and on the website.

I am completely new to charsets, it's the first time I am building a website in a language that is not supported like in this case..

Could someone please tell me what's the problem here? and what I have to do to make this work in russian language?

Comment: How do you insert the russian text into the database? Could you show some code?

Comment: I agree with @watain, editing your question and adding code would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't told your database to support multibyte characters. Set it to use UTF-8.